# How to set BIOS Password on Windows 8.1/8 to Ensure Security

Tags: passwords

As we all know that BIOS password is the first protection layer for our computer. But not so many people know how to set BIOS password on Windows 8.1/8 to ensure securtiy? I need the answers. Help me, please.

Comment: The answer below is correct. Just to correct your assumption, BIOS password is password on the motherboard BIOS (or in the case of newer motherboard UEFI). This is loaded even before your Windows or other OS are running. Additional note that BIOS and UEFI have several password. The most common one set is to prevent anyone accessing BIOS/UEFI and changing the settings. The additional one would be the HDD password (which prevents the HDD being accessed - again before loading the OS). And then once the OS is up (you got Windows login screen) you set your Login Password.

Answer (score 2):

### UEFI

Note that this method only works on boards supporting, and having UEFI enabled by default.

With the advent of the newer Windows 8/8.1 devices, manufacturers started making laptops and desktops alike with `UEFI` or `Unified Extensible Firmware Interface` which is an extension of `EFI`, `Extensible Firmware Interface`. This means that the PC will (usually) POST within a second, helping Windows 8/8.1 to boot quicker. To enter the UEFI, you need to do this from within Windows:

1. Open the charms bar <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or swipe in from the right edge of the screen
2. Click `PC Settings`
3. Click `Recovery and Startup`
4. Click `Recovery`
5. Click `Reboot` under the `Advanced Startup` heading
6. Once in advanced startup, click `Advanced Options`
7. Click `UEFI Settings`
8. Done

### BIOS

Note: This is for **legacy** systems, with only BIOS.

There are 6 keys that I know of for the legacy BIOS implementations. these are:

<kbd>F1</kbd>
<kbd>F2</kbd>
<kbd>F9</kbd>
<kbd>F10</kbd>
<kbd>DEL</kbd>
<kbd>ESC</kbd>

1. Start the PC while pressing one of these keys
2. If one doesn't work, try the next.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the first protection ‘layer’ is a locked room so there is no access to the computer box. Without that the BIOS password has no effect as anyone can open the box and clear the CMOS.

You set the BIOS password before booting any OS, via the BIOS utility.

Comment: The OP asked *how* to do so, not an explanation of *why* his reasoning is wrong.

Comment: I am then not included in all who know that the BIOS password is the first line of defense. And there are no multiple answers to what the OP seeks, there is only one way to do this. Press the key which brings up your BIOS menu (varies from the Escape key to the F1-F12 and other variations, depending on the BIOS maker) after the PC powers up. Which, by the way has nothing to with what OS is installed or how many.